# TCP Duplicate Acknowledgement

Tags: network, tcp, networking, network-theory

Host A and Host B has establish the connection, Host A will send a segment 1,2,3,4,5,6 but segment number 2 and 5 is lost. Then the receiver will sending an duplicate ACK to sender, so whenever sender receive 3 duplicate ACK then the sender will retransmit the loss segment. But in this case where segment number 2 and 5 is loss how is the process, does 6 duplicate ACK will send by the receiver, remembering we lost 2 segment the segment 2 and 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A duplicate ACK is send when packets are received out of order which indicate that something is lost in between. In your scenario this will be:

- B receives 1 -> will ACK 1
- B receives 3 (2 lost) -> will **again** (duplicate) ACK 1
- B receives 4 (2 still lost) -> will **again** ACK 1
- B receives 6 (2 and 5 lost) -> will **again** ACK 1

So there are 3 duplicate ACK, one for each packet received out of order.

Hopefully A now realizes that 2 is lost and will retransmit it:

- B receives 2 (5 still lost) -> will ACK 4 (assuming that B did not discard 3 and 4 yet)

Now A might realize that 5 is still lost and will retransmit it:

- B receives 5 -> will ACK 6 (assuming B did not discard 6 yet)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation sir